# how to solve error occured while trying dynamic data POST request from body

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, backend

> the error occured when i try post method to retrieve the data on the body (on postman) and store that data in to a mongodb local database then error occured says bad request with status 400

*this is app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var mongoose = require("mongoose");

//mongoose make sure that only the fields that are specified in your Schema will be saved in the database
//strict query
mongoose.set('strictQuery',true); 

mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/EMP',{
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
},(err) => {
  if(err)
    console.log(err);
  else
    console.log('successfully connected to MongoDB');
});

var studentModel = require("./model/students.model");

var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var studentsRouter = require('./routes/students');
var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/students', studentsRouter);
// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

*this is model.students.js file(path ./model/model.students.js)

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

//lets create schema 
var studentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    studentId : Number,
    firstName : String,
    lastName : String,
    age : Number,
    dept : String
  });
  
  //lets create a model which is instance of schema 
  
  var studentModel = mongoose.model("students",studentSchema);
  
  module.exports = studentModel;
```

*this is students.js file(path ./routes/students.js)

```
var express = require('express');
const studentModel = require('../model/students.model');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.send('students route works pretty well');
});

// route to add some data in the database
router.post('/add', function (req, res) {
 //   we are creating instance of model-studentModel called studentObj
    let studentObj = new studentModel({
        studentId: req.body.studentId,
        firstName: req.body.firstName,
        lastName: req.body.lastName,
        age: req.body.age,
        dept: req.body.dept
    });
    studentObj.save(function(err,studentObj){
        if(err)
            res.send(err);
        else
            res.send({message: "students data has been succefully added",object: studentObj});
    });
    var data = req.data;
    console.log(data);
});
module.exports = router;
```

*this is error occured

> it says status code 400 bad request with bad syntax i don't know why this happened i read documentations but i can't find what i am missing and causing this problem

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Unexpected token s in JSON at position 7</h1>
    <h2>400</h2>
    <pre>SyntaxError: Unexpected token s in JSON at position 7
    at JSON.parse (&lt;anonymous&gt;)
    at parse (C:\Users\Nile-Tech\3D Objects\project\Express JS\EMP\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:89:19)
    at C:\Users\Nile-Tech\3D Objects\project\Express JS\EMP\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:128:18
    at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (node:async_hooks:203:9)
    at invokeCallback (C:\Users\Nile-Tech\3D Objects\project\Express JS\EMP\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:231:16)
    at done (C:\Users\Nile-Tech\3D Objects\project\Express JS\EMP\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:220:7)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (C:\Users\Nile-Tech\3D Objects\project\Express JS\EMP\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:280:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)</pre>
</body>

</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZ6wP.png)

Answer (score 1):

You sent malformed body with invalid JSON. You probably send `&lt;anonymous&gt;` which isn't a JSON valid format.

Check you request body and ensure that it contains a valid JSON and encoded properly.

Comment: I have added screenshot from postman which i tried , can you take a look?

Comment: all keys must be string type, so instead of `{ someKey: 0}`, use quotes like `{ "someKey": 0}`